# Nokogiri with Ruby 2.0.0p0 on OSX Mountain Lion (no such file to load)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have installed nokogiri on my system running OSX 10.8.3, Ruby 2.0.0p0, Rails 3.2.13. When trying to run a simple test script beginning with

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
```

I get the error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Users/jerome/Documents/MyFiles/Developer/testruby.rb:2
```

Does nokogiri currently support Ruby 2.0 on OSX?

edit: This issue arose while building from Sublime Text 2. Script works fine on irb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri is supported.

In the initial question, I had been building from Sublime Text 2. This produced the error, whereas doing so on irb worked fine.

The solution from http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2012/12/07/sublime-text-2-rvm-rspec-take-2/ worked for me. This changed the default path Sublime was finding Ruby in.

Solution:

Update ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build to

```
{
  "env":{
      "PATH":"${HOME}/.rvm/bin:${PATH}"
  },
  "cmd": ["rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

Also, I apologize for my mistake of not initially posting that I was getting the error from Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 0):

The path shown in your error output indicates you're using the system-default version of Ruby (1.8.7), since it is referencing `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8`. You likely need to ensure you're using the correct `ruby` binary for 2.0.

If you installed via RVM, you can run something like `rvm use 2.0.0`, or use a `.ruby-version` or `.rvmrc` file in your source project. Or else simply invoke the 2.0.0 `ruby` binary directly.

Comment: Indeed I installed with RVM. `rvm use 2.0.0` does not solve the problem. `ruby -v` is showing ruby 2.0.0p0 already.

Comment: `- GEM PATHS:
- /Users/jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0`
   `  - /Users/jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global`

Comment: What does the first line (the shebang) of `testruby.rb` look like?

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. Please take a look. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! I was wondering if you also were perhaps hardcoding the shebang executable path to `/usr/bin/ruby` instead of `/usr/bin/env ruby`, but the Sublime PATH issue seems like the root cause.